# Connecting the protective ground of a 3 phase AC motor

Tags: power, inverter

I am wondering how can I connect the protective earth of my 3 phase AC motor? 
Here is the background of how my connections are:
I am using 3 phase with a neutral point from the mains which goes to  wye-wye transformers. The stepped down voltage is then fed into a 3 phase diode bridge rectifier, which is then fed into a 3 phase MOSFET bridge inverter. Now I want to connect the inverter output to my 3 phase motor, but I am not sure where should I connect the protective earth of the motor?

Answer (score 3):

> I am not sure where should I connect the protective earth of the
>   motor?

The protective earth of your motor should go to exactly the same place as if it were directly connected to your incoming AC 3-ph supply - it must go to a reliable earth for safety reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Connect it to the protective earth terminal on your rectifier-inverter unit.

Here's an example connection diagram from the Danfoss AquaDrive manual MG.20.N5.02 (VLT AQUA Drive Design Guide)

[image]

Note that the earth wire is likely to be polluted with electrical noise, so inside a commercially-produced VSD, there is likely to be a filter between the motor earth terminal and the supply earth terminal.

If you are using a home-built VSD and have no such filter, just connect them to the same earth bar.